# error using gmail api tuto using python 3 "except errors.HttpError, error:"

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

I get an error with the first line:

```
except errors.HttpError, error:
   print (f'An error occurred: {error}')
   return None
```

(The line 2 has been updated for python 3. Only the parenthesis to print are mandatory)

Comment: How to import "errors"?

Comment: @derek try `from apiclient import errors, discovery  #needed for gmail service`

Answer (score 13):

You must switch the `,` with a `as`:

```
except errors.HttpError as error:
   print (f'An error occurred: {error}')
   return None
```

Comment: Works for me. Thanks.